# Как сделать ссылку на html шабон в javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, opencart

Пытаюсь сделать уведомления о добавлении товара в закладки и сравнение с изображениями и другими плюшками. В чем проблема - у меня все работает, но мне не нравится, что html-код вывода окна popup лежит в хедере, я хотел бы вынести его в файл `template/product/compare` отдельным `div` с `id`, но не могу понять, как это сделать.

Вот код common js в части compare:

```js
var compare = {
    'add': function(product_id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=product/compare/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                $('.alert').remove();

                if (json['success']) {
                    $("div.hover-product").hide();
                    $("#notification .modal-footer");
                    $("#notification").modal('show');
                    $("#notification h4").html(json['compare-heading']);
                    $("#notification .mod-text").html(json['success']);
                    $("#notification .mod-image").html(json['product_pic']);
                    $("#notification .modal-footer").html(json['product_pic']);
                    $('#compare-total').html(json['total']);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    'remove': function() {

    }
}
```

Версия Opencart 2.1.x

Comment: Попробуйте использовать функцию load(): http://api.jquery.com/load/ .

Comment: спасибо, но все равно не могу разобраться где ее вставить, я пока новичек

Comment: подгрузку html-файла через `load()` можно делать где угодно, главное, чтобы это происходило не позже, чем вы будете добавлять туда данные